# Which latent variable model is better to find hidden variable?

Tags: feature-engineering, markov-hidden-model, expectation-maximization

Currently, I am exploring the concept of `latent variable` for `regression type datasets`.

I have gone through literature of few of the `methods and models` used in finding `latent variable`, like: ***EM algorithms**, **Partial least square regression**, **Latent semantic analysis**, **Mixed Effect models (linear-nonlinear)**, **HMM**, and there are many more!!*

For Example:

```py
volume DataFrame head is 
    length     width      volume
0  1.395702  4.822958    40.821677
1  5.761620  9.912682   242.571731
2  3.444930  2.111199    18.904144
3  6.236642  7.609429   425.838818
4  7.270517  1.106117    39.883937
```

In the above mentioned dataset, `height`, `type-of-object`, `units` and other parameters are missing. As mentioned by people previously, it is difficult to regenerate them as such but there is a possibility of acknowledging them using `latent variable`.

Hence, I would like to ask which `method` or `model` will be more suited for such kind of dataset?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. There's a bit of confusion in your question, for example EM is a method used in various types of models but it's not a model by itself. Generally there's no such thing as "the best model for everything", different models have different characteristics and different applications. Do you have a particular kind of problem in mind?

Comment: @Erwan thanks for the kind response! Apologies for the vague question! Yeah I am trying to find hidden variables for a given dataset (linear regression). Hence, I want to know which model or method will be better to start with. As, I have seen few examples on the web but nothing particular to this type of problem. Please do advise and suggest!!